# Vue2 Custom directive to disable button conditionally

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I'm trying to create a custom directive to conditionally disable a button. Currently my html looks like this:

```
<button v-if="someConditionIsTrue" @click="doTheThing">Do something</button>
<button v-else class="disabled">Do something</button>
```

With the disabled class just applying some styling.

It works fine but I would like the html to look like this instead:

```
<button v-disable-if="someConditionIsTrue" @click="doTheThing">Do something</button>
```

Here is a working codepen where I manage to do it by just setting the disabled flag on the button.

https://codepen.io/stevgouws/pen/yRGerW

However that's obviously not secure as they can just edit it in dev tools.

Here's another one I did by using @click.native and e.preventDefault but then I don't know how to manage restoring the click functionality if the condition changes.

```
  Vue.directive('disableIf', {
    bind(el, binding, vnode) {
    if (binding.value) {
      el.classList.add("disabled")
      el.onclick = e => {
        if (binding.value) e.preventDefault()
      }  
    } else {
      el.classList.remove("disabled")
    }
  },
  update(el, binding, vnode) {
    if (binding.value) {
      el.classList.add("disabled")
      el.onclick = e => {
        if (binding.value) e.preventDefault()
      }        
    } else {
      el.classList.remove("disabled")
    }
  }
});
```

Codepen here-> https://codepen.io/stevgouws/pen/JmwXGE

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can disable the button directly **without the need of a custom directive** by using the `:disabled="someCondition"` hmtl attribute. Note the use of  `:` so that it binds to the `someCondition` property of the vm.

Using your example:

```
<div id="app">
  <button :disabled="someCondition" @click="doTheThing">Do the thing</button>
  <button @click="someCondition = !someCondition">Toggle Condition</button>
</div>
```

And use the `button:disabled` css selector to apply your styles.

```
button:disabled {
  opacity: 0.4;
}
```

Here's a fork of your pen https://codepen.io/dormenog/pen/jeXqYO?editors=0100.

With regards to preventing the click event, you can use the same property as a conditional to prevent the click event handler from proceeding. For example

```
doTheThing($event) {
    if (this.someCondition) {
        return;
    }

    //do stuff
}
```

On a production build of a Vue application, you should not have access to the dev tools. A user could potentially enable the button through the DOM but the conditional inside the method would prevent the action from proceeding.

Keep in mind that you can use the `:disabled="foo"` binding in any html element that supports it natively, i.e. Input fields, anchor tags and text areas.

Comment: Thanks, this works but this doesn't solve my problem. I don't want to have to go and wrap each function in a conditional. What I like about the idea of a v-disabled-if directive is that you only have to declare the conditional once, instead of twice.

Comment: Using a directive seems like an overkill, and in my opinion, preventing the event propagation falls out of the responsibility of a directive. In general, disabling the button should be enough. If you are worried about people manipulating the dom, maybe a better approach would be to conditionally render the button instead of disabling it, using ‘v-if’ so that the button does not exist in the Dom when the condition is falsy.

Comment: I don't know you might be right but to me it seems like the ideal simple and clean solution (usage wise). But maybe it's not possible. Using v-if is what I'm currently doing. (See beginning of my post).

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do the same thing and I think I found a simple and ‘elegant’ solution.

`Wrapper.vue`

```
<template>
  <div>
    <slot :disabled="disabledModel" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Role',

  data: () => ({
    disabledModel: false,
  }),

  computed: {
    disabled: {
      get() {
        return this.disabledModel
      },
      set(value) {
        this.disabledModel = value
      },
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

`main.js` - directive
...

```
Vue.directive('wrapper', {
    bind: function (el, binding, vnode) {
        vnode.componentOptions.propsData.disabled = true //here
      }
}
```

In my component

```
     <wrapper v-wrapper v-slot="slotProps">
        <v-btn
          color="primary"
          v-bind="slotProps"
        >
          Something
        </v-btn>
      </wrapper>
```